# How to download the file tiago_public.rosinstall

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am fairly new to programming with ROS and Linux in general and I need help. I am currently doing the "Installing TIAGo Simulation" tutorial an got stuck on step number on. I don't know what to do in this step:

" Download the file tiago_public.rosinstall. Copy the rosinstall file in ~/tiago_public_ws. "

(could some someone go step-by-step and explain what I should type in the terminal, line by line, please!!)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327434/how-to-download-the-file-tiago_public.rosinstall/) by [MAU](https://answers.ros.org/users/43736/mau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The text you quote actually contains a link to the file that the author wants you to download:

> Download the file [tiago_public.rosinstall](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pal-robotics/tiago_tutorials/kinetic-devel/tiago_public-melodic.rosinstall). Copy the rosinstall file in ~/tiago_public_ws. Then run the following instruction in order to clone all the required repositories within the workspace:

The `tiago_public.rosinstall` there is a link to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pal-robotics/tiago_tutorials/kinetic-devel/tiago_public-melodic.rosinstall.

To download that file would be no different from how you'd download it on Windows or OSX: right click the link and select *Save link as* (or whatever the equivalent is for your browser). Then select your workspace as instructed in the tutorial.

Alternatively, you could use a command like the following to download it using `wget`:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pal-robotics/tiago_tutorials/kinetic-devel/tiago_public-melodic.rosinstall -O $HOME/tiago_public_ws/
```

that would immediately place the downloaded file in the `tiago_public_ws` directory in your `$HOME` directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MAU](https://answers.ros.org/users/43736/mau/) on 2019-07-02**:
Thank you! This appears to have worked. After I typed this into my terminal ( rosinstall src /opt/ros/kinetic tiago_public.rosinstall ) in order to clone all the required repositories, and it also apeered to have downloaded a bunch of packages.

But midway I did some warnings and errors. I don't know whether to be concerned or simply ignore them...

error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
OR
ERROR in config: Error processing...

Example:   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pal-robotics/pmb2_simulation.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (cntlr.airrowdy.utsa.edu) does not match target host name 'github.com'

Is this some kind of network error?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-02**:
Are you behind a network proxy of some kind? If so, that could explain this.